# Django - serialize models to json for use as JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, json, django

I need to get the data from my models as an object in Javascript. 
I use this in my JS code ("data" being part of the context returned in my Django view) :

```
var data= {{ data|safe }};
```

And in my view I have :

```
context = {'data': {
             'model1': serializers.serialize('json', model1.objects.all()),
             'model2': serializers.serialize('json', model2.objects.all()),
          }
```

The problems I have are :

1) I get an error in JS unless I use "safe" on the context variable,

2) Even if I use "safe", the object is unusable because it is just a string (i.e. data.model1[0] return "[" instead of the first element in the array).

What is the proper way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that while the *values* of `data` are valid JSON, `data` itself is a Python dict which is not valid as JSON.

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to separate out the variables:

```
var data = {
    model1: {{ data.model1|safe }},
    model2: {{ data.model2|safe }}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `json` module, a solution could be:

```
import json

data = {
        'model1': json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', model1.objects.all())),
        'model2': json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', model2.objects.all())),
       }
context = {'data': json.dumps(data)}
```

then `var data = {{data|safe}}`